# Why does [service-name.asmx]/[function-name]< br > get included before my webservice json response? Causes ParserError failure from ajax

Tags: json, ajax, vb.net, web-services

I have a HelloWorld WebMethod in my vb.net developed web service.   It returns json.   I am using an ajax request to pull the data back.  The ajax request fails every time, stating parsererror.   The reason is because the responseText from my webservice is putting data before the json:

```
responseText=response = "/troy.asmx/HelloWorld< br >{\"d\":\"Hello World\"}"
```

************   My Web Service:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")>
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
Public Class troy
  Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

  <WebMethod()>
  Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
  End Function
End Class
```

'********  Jquery  *************

```
function processTroyTest2(s1, s2, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "troy.asmx/HelloWorld",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response.d);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      callback(false, '')
    }
  });
}
```

I have been searching online for DAYS trying to find out why /troy.asmx/HelloWorld
 is in the webservice response.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see on the server side what it's actually sending as the response so you can compare what's sent vs what Ajax reports?  I don't code ajax but that would be the first thing I'd look at.  Because right now you don't whether the issue is one with piece of code, the other, or both together.  This might help you narrow it down.

Comment: Yes.   I can break the web service and see that I am returning the following "Hello World".   .NET converts it to json.   Why is the other stuff in there?